# unable to read text file using stream reader and place txt into custom class

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class, streamreader

so i am trying to read text from a txt file and then add the text in to a custom class list,

the code is

```
public static List<BookInfo> LoadCSVFile(string fileName, out string qError)
    {
        qError = "";
        fileName = "books.txt";
        List<BookInfo> Book_Info = new List<BookInfo>();
        StreamReader read = null;

        try
        {
            read = new StreamReader(fileName);
            while (!read.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = read.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                if (values.Length == 3)
                {
                    string Title = values[0].Trim();
                    string Author = values[1].Trim();
                    string ISBN = values[2].Trim();

                    try
                    {
                        Book_Info.Add(new BookInfo(Title, Author, ISBN));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        qError = ex.Message;
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    qError = $"line {line} was unable to be read";
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            qError = $"failed to open file: {fileName}";
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (read != null)
            {
                read.Close();
            }
        }
        if (qError == "")
        {
            return Book_Info;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

once i have read the text it will be displayed in a form which i believe to be coded correctly

i have placed an error message in to show when the file has been read and each time i try something new the same error appears.

have i gone wrong somewhere when reading the txt file?

Edit:

Text file was created using visual studio and is in the same solution, text file is in bin/debug

Comment: Where is your file located? You have to pass file path in `StreamReader()` , if file is not present in bin folder

Comment: I created the txt file within visual studio and is in the same solution

Comment: Before `StreamReader()`, Check `if(File.Exists(fileName))`; I guess you have not changed property of text file to **Copy Always**.

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with thegeneral's answer, but to answer your initial question I suspect your books.txt file was not located in your [Bin/Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS8oq.png) folder. [I did test your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKyCP.png) ;-P

Answer (score 2):

Some notes

1. if you are going to use something that Implements [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), it's always good practice to use the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement
2. If this is only a small file, why bother with `StreamReader` when you can just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Linq is your friend, projection is a wonderful thing.
4. If you really want to parse a CSV file, I'd seriously consider a dedicated CSV parser library (like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)). It will save you many headaches

This is not really the bastion of perfect coding, however I tried to work with what you had and the spirit of what you were trying to do.

**Some code:**

```
public static List<BookInfo> LoadCSVFile(string fileName, out string qError)
{
   try
   {

      // read all lines in to another type
      // just makes it easier for errors which you seem to want
      var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                      .Select(x => new { Values = x.Split(','), Text = x })
                      .ToList();

      // get a list of errors, 
      var errors = lines.Where(x => x.Values.Length != 3)
                        .Select((s, i) => $"Bad book! Line {i} : {s.Text}");

      // return some errors
      qError = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);

      // project lines to your books    
      return lines.Where(x => x.Values.Length == 3)
                  .Select(x => new BookInfo(x.Values[0], x.Values[0], x.Values[0]))
                  .ToList();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      qError = e.Message;
   }

   return null;
}
```

**Disclaimer**

- I wouldn't usually catch errors like this, it's rather nasty
- The whole anonymous type and returning errors is a bit smelly, if the file is corrupt, I'd just throw a big nasty exception and be done with it. Make the user do the right thing
- This **is** going to fail the second you have a title with a comma in it
- This is completely untested!